# What is the cause of error code 255 in PhantomJS and how to fix it?

Tags: phantomjs

While executing PhantomJS from a Jenkins job, I get regularly error codes 255 as follows :

```
20140804 18:43:55.362,10,SEVERE,"Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (PhantomJS Unit Test) on project XXXXXX: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255) -> [Help 1]",hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener,
```

I ran Maven in debug mode, but I could not get more information. The issue appears after all tests have been run. There is one single failure, but the build is not supposed to fail.

Have you experienced this behavior ? What might be the cause for error code 255 and how to fix it ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the problem and the solution.

One of our teams wrote a custom jasmin test runner for phantom.js which was calling `phantom.exit(-1)` with no log message under specific circumstances. As values not within `[0-255]` range are illegal from the point of view of phantomjs, it was exiting with an error code `255`. We added log messages and changed the return code and now everything's fine.

Hope this helps.